# Json camel casing properties

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

https://dotnetfiddle.net/R96sPn

I am trying to create `AddJsonObject` such that the `name` of `External.AddParameter` obeys whatever the ContractRevolver is set for `External.Serialize`

In the example below it is camel casing, but as you can see the output is not camel cased. Changing the ContractResolver should effectively determine the formatting of the `name` parameter.  No additional code can be added to `External` class

This is a class that I cannot modify:

```
public static class External
{
    public static string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer{
            ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(), 
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        };

        using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (JsonTextWriter jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter((TextWriter)stringWriter))
            {
                jsonTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                jsonTextWriter.QuoteChar = '"';
                ser.Serialize((JsonWriter)jsonTextWriter, obj);
                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void AddParameter(string name, string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name + " : " + str);
    }
}
```

Just example class:

```
  public class Product { public Product ChildProduct { get; set; } public string Name { get; set; } public DateTime Expiry { get; set; } public string[] Sizes { get; set; } }
```

Main:

```
public class Program
{
    public void AddJsonObject(object obj)
    {
        foreach (var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var propValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);
            External.AddParameter(property.Name, External.Serialize(propValue));
        }
    }

    public void Main()
    {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.Name = "Apple";
        product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
        product.Sizes = new string[]{"small", "big"};

        product.ChildProduct = new Product();

        AddJsonObject(product);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ChildProduct : {
  "expiry": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
}
Name : "Apple"
Expiry : "2008-12-28T00:00:00"
Sizes : [
  "small",
  "big"
]
```

Desired Output:

```
childProduct : {
  "expiry": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
}
name : "Apple"
expiry : "2008-12-28T00:00:00"
sizes : [
  "small",
  "big"
]
```

This demo showcases Serialize using JSON.net with CamelCase, but AddJsonObject should work independent of what json serializer they use or what formatting. This example just showcases a non-trivial example.

My initial attempt consisted of wrapping the object into a parent object. `External.Serialize()` the wrapper object then somehow feed the results into `AddParameter` such that the `name` is the output of the serialization -- Couldn't get this to work right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have a solution that works, but Ill hold off anymore clever answers come up

```
public void AddJsonObject(object obj)
{
    var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(External.Serialize(obj));
    foreach (var property in jsonObj.Properties())
    {
        External.AddParameter(property.Name, External.Serialize( property.Value));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Line where you initialize ContractResolver (`ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()`) to

```
ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
{
    NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
};
```

Comment: Thats in `External` which I have no control if or how they setup the json serializer, I can only use it and my AddJsonObject must obey it